# Calculating values of field based on two others using Field Calculator in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

I need to combine two fields in an attribute table.  I want to do this using the field calculator.  What is the proper script to write to combine a field called "name" and "type", so that it produces one field with "name type"?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Answer (score 4):

When in VBScript mode the sytnax would be

```
[name]&[type]
```

To add some separation you can use:

```
[name] & "-" & [type]
```

to put a dash between the two values.