# How do I merge two columns into one column steps?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, table

When I save the table after I set up the classifcation and then ArcGIS save it as a INFO file and then you have two columns that you want to merge into one. Is there a better way to do that ? What I want to get the columns from FROM and TO merge into One column. These are the feet Elevation numbers.

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Do you want to add the values? Subtract one from the other? Show both in the same column (2800, 2900)? or...?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not explain enough.. What I want is to show the elevation to be like 2800 to 2900, for example.

Comment: check this out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/how-do-you-calculate-values-of-a-field-based-on-two-others-using-field-calculato

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this task, you'll need to make sure that the field you are calculating to is a text field. Right-click on the field's header in the layer's attribute table and click 'Field Calculator'. If the Field Calculator dialog box, choose 'Python' as your Parser.

Then, in the Output = box, type:

```
str( !FROM!) + " to " + str( !TO!)
```

Hit OK you should see the desired results.

Or, with 'VB Script' as your Parser:

[FROM] & " to " & [TO]